# Is there a difference between "has" and "is"?

Tags: american-english, auxiliary-verbs, spelling

In a English or American perspective of the difference because I sometimes have trouble making the difference is means a thing and has is owned but I sometimes have trouble making the difference

For instance, "is" and "has" seem to have the same meaning here:

> there **is** a toy
>
> someone **has** the toy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: _Is_ is part of the verb _to be_ and _has_ of _to have_. You need to tell us more about the kind of sentence where you find them confusing.

Comment: Can you give some examples of sentences that give you problems?

Comment: there is a toy or soemone has the toy

Answer (score 2):

"Has" and "is" are different words, unrelated except they can both be used as auxiliary verbs. I don't think there's any meaning overlap between them in English.

THAT SAID, the functions they have in English are different than in other languages, like yours. In English, we use "be" for both *identity* and *existence/location*:

> (1) She is a teacher. (*identity*)
> (2) She is in the classroom. (*existence/location*)

and we use "have" for *possession*:

> (3) She has twenty students.

But in Korean, for instance, we use the verb 이다 ("ida") only for *identity*, and we use 있다 ("issda") for *existence/location* and *possession*.

Here's a gloss of Korean sentence structure:

> (1) She teacher ***ida***.  (*identity*)
> (2) She classroom-in ***issda***.  (*existence/location*)
> (3) She twenty students ***issda***.  (*possession*)

I'm assuming it's the same in your language if you're not a Korean speaker. So it's your job as a language learner to figure out if a sentence is about *existence or location*, and then remember to use "be" verbs, rather than "have" verbs.

Comment: If you are a Korean speaker, comment below and I'll give you more examples in chat.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a toy** and **Someone has the toy** have distinct meanings and are used in different contexts.

**There is a toy** is used to point out a toy in some place, or express that a toy exists. It would normally be qualified by giving the location of the toy ("There is a toy on the floor") or describing the toy ("There is a toy that says hello whenever you come into the room"). "Is" indicates *existence* - if you want to pick up or buy the toy, you can, but it doesn't say anything about who owns the toy.

**Someone has the toy** means that the toy is in the possession of someone. It's not lying on the floor. Someone has picked it up and is holding it. "Has" indicates *possession* - it can either refer to the owner of the toy, or to someone who is currently holding or playing with the toy.